# Discord.js - Command that after 10 seconds if you not typing something it will tell you you run of time

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to do bot in js that when users do the command: !mugg @someone //someone is another user mention.
it will say: The Mugger is approaching ${user}, and then after 10 seconds if the user that got mugged won't type !killmugger he will get the message The Mugger mugged ${user} but if he does he will get the message: The mugger didn't mug ${user}.
This is what i tried to do: (I tried to play with if and roles)

```js
    bot.on("message", (message) => {
      let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
      bot.user.setActivity("!mugg @someone");

      switch (args[0]) {
        case "mug":
          const user = message.mentions.members.first();
          let Role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("772195872133742634");

          if (user) {
            const member = message.guild.member(user);

            if (member) {
              message.reply(`The Mugger is approaching ${user}`);
              user.roles.add("Role");
            } else {
              message.reply("That user isn't in this server.");
            }
          } else {
            message.reply("You need to mention a user");
          }
          setTimeout(function () {
            if (!message.mentions.roles.has("772195872133742634")) {
              message.channel.send(`The Mugger mugged ${user}`);
              user.roles.remove(Role);
            }
          }, 10000);
          break;

        case "killmugger":
          const user1 = message.mentions.members.first();
          let Role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.get("772195872133742634");

          if (!message.mentions.roles.has("772195872133742634")) {
            message.channel.send(`The Mugger not mugged ${user1}`);
            user1.roles.remove(Role1);
          }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Check out https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,

Like @Saddy mentioned you can use [awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages), in the following way you don't need to verify if the user has the needed roles.

```js
 message.channel.send(`The Mugger mugged ${user}`);

 //filter where m is message and the author needs to be the user you mentioned and the content needs to be equal to killmugger or you can change it to !killmugger
 const filter = m => m.author.id == user!.id && m.content.toLowerCase() == "killmugger"
 //awaitMessage function max: maximum messages, time: in milliseconds and the errors in this case we just need time to make sure that after 
 //10s it will return the message if he doesn't write killmuger in time
 message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] }).then(m => {
  return console.log("He got it in time")
   }).catch(() => {
  return message.channel.send(`The Mugger not mugged ${user1}`);
   })
```